# Problem with i2c_hid kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, blacklist

I have got a problem with i2c_hid kernel module.
During boot i see this message:

```
[   30.340216] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
```

This take a very long time (~10 seconds) to fix by itself.

Here are the output of dmseg | grep i2c

```
[    5.088380] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: i2c-SYNA3063:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.088388] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: Linked as a consumer to regulator.0
[    5.088389] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: i2c-SYNA3063:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.917177] [<00000000587c051b>] i2c_dw_isr [i2c_designware_core]
[   10.372250] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   17.028217] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   23.684215] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   30.340216] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   31.492215] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: can't add hid device: -61
[   31.492587] i2c_hid: probe of i2c-SYNA3063:00 failed with error -61
[  793.402149] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: i2c-SYNA3063:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[  793.402159] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: i2c-SYNA3063:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[  798.543825] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  804.687710] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  810.831603] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  816.975397] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  817.999421] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: can't add hid device: -61
[  817.999733] i2c_hid: probe of i2c-SYNA3063:00 failed with error -61
```

here are the output of dmseg -l err

```
[    5.071005] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[    5.085339] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [ IBUS ]
[    5.917130] irq 17: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[    5.917174] handlers:
[    5.917177] [<00000000587c051b>] i2c_dw_isr [i2c_designware_core]
[    6.366111] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
[   10.372250] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   17.028217] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   23.684215] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   30.340216] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[   31.492215] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: can't add hid device: -61
[   32.740583] kvm: disabled by bios
[   32.826100] kvm: disabled by bios
[   32.944271] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.034443] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.139257] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.273601] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.360587] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.449016] kvm: disabled by bios
[   33.543923] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   33.543928] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   33.545081] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   33.545557] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   33.547296] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   33.551802] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   33.552720] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   35.012983] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[   43.255520] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[   44.006870] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   44.006880] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   44.006889] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   44.006894] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   44.007541] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   54.014665] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   54.015679] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   54.024418] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   54.024431] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   54.024440] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   54.817376] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[   64.012385] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   64.012413] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   64.012421] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   64.012426] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   64.012986] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   73.806595] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   73.806614] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   73.806621] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   73.806626] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   73.807231] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   83.738322] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   83.738332] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   83.738340] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   83.738346] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[   83.738810] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[  798.543825] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  804.687710] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  810.831603] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  816.975397] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: failed to reset device.
[  817.999421] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA3063:00: can't add hid device: -61
```

here are the output of "lsmod | grep i2c"

```
i2c_hid                28672  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
i2c_i801               28672  0
hid                   139264  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_generic,hid_asus
```

I did think that i should remove i2c_hid and hid kernel modules. So i tried put them in the blacklist putting them in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. in this file i added "blacklist i2c_hid" and "blacklist hid". But they start anyway. I tried to put "modprobe.blacklist=i2c_hid,hid" in the kernel parameters, but this didn't worked too. Any Idea?

Thank you very much
.
.
.
.
.
PS:I'm not exactly on ubuntu. I'm on debian 10.5, but i had this problem in ubuntu 18.04 too.
PS:I know that i2c_hid is a touchpad driver